# Flask Method Not Allowed Simple HTML Form Submission

Tags: flask, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to learn Flask.

I have an extremely simple app running on pythonanywhere.

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'CONNECT', 'OPTIONS', 'TRACE', 'PATCH'])
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Flask!'
```

HTML Form:

```
<body>

    <h1>Post Data Form</h1>

    <form action="https://think2grow.pythonanywhere.com" method="POST">
        <!-- Add your form fields here -->
        <label for="data">Data:</label>
        <input type="text" id="data" name="data" required>

        <!-- Add more fields as needed -->

        <br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

When I navigate to the site, I see the "Hello from Flask!" message. When I submit the form, I get a "Method Not Allowed" message.

Tried to enable all methods. Not sue why the app won't accept the POST message.

Comment: You have hard-coded an absolute url into your form html. This is almost always a bad idea as your form will submitted here during development as well as production. If you remove this then your form will be submitted back to the route that it was originally served from.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it seems as if you are opening the HTML page directly rather than accessing it by typing the URL from the browser. While using flask, we have to render the HTML page in the Python code using the `render_template` method rather than directly opening the HTML file. On similar lines, if you want to use data received from the form, you have to write the logic within the Python file to handle the POST request.

Currently, there seems to be no link between the Python file and the HTML file. We need to have the link for the Flask application to work. In your example, the code has to be modified as follows

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form['data']
        return f"Response submitted is {data}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Make sure the HTML form is in `templates/` in the root of your app. Also as suggested in comments you can change `action = "/"` within the form tag and still make this work.